# Why Doesn't This Regex Lookahead Work?

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, regex-lookarounds

I am designing a regex to use in some IIS Url Rewrites. The intent is to capture urls which:

1. Are not just a file (as identified by containing a period) in the root directory, and
2. Do not contain a querystring, and
3. Do not belong to a specific set of sub-directories, specifically "Account" and "Public"

My current regex looks like:

```
^(?!(Account)|(Public))([^./]+)(/[^?]*)?$
```

Using [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com) with the test set of:

```
file.aspx
Account/otherfile.aspx
Public/otherfile.aspx
otherfolder1/otherfile.aspx?stuff=otherstuff
otherfolder2/otherfolder/otherfile.aspx
otherfolder3/
otherfolder4
```

My regex correctly ignores the first two cases, but it is still matching on the third case. What is wrong with the lookahead here?

Comment: This... seems like it's working as expected in RegexPal for me.  You only want the last 3 in your example to match, correct?

Comment: Correct. For me it matches 2, 3, 5, 6, and 7.

Comment: Ok, that's really strange. I had spaced my examples out in my actual test - placing a blank line between each. If I remove the blank lines, it does give the desired results.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure entirely what's going on there.  For what it's worth, I did a quick test in C# and it also produces the correct results.

Comment: Just for the record `(?!(Account)|(Public))` is a negative lookahead, not a lookbehind. And the parentheses around `Account` and `Public` don't do anything, because a lookahead doesn't participate in the match. Should be like this I believe: `(?!Account|Public)`. Otherwise, the regex does indeed seem to work, though not in RegExPal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported by [sln](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10255155/259014), the problem with these tests in RegexPal is that running a multi-line test enables multiple lines to group together to create a single match when they otherwise shouldn't.

The regex is fine for the purposes that it is designed to fulfill. It's actually overkill. For IIS Rewrites and Redirects, if you are using the [IIS URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/), you have the option of specifying conditions on which it will or will not accept matches. Some of those options include:

- Item is not a physical file
- Item is not a physical directory
- Item does (or does not) match a secondary pattern

These will achieve the desired effect more completely than the negative-lookahead.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't resist trying to come up with something that would work in RegExPal (did not succeed - **Edit: just verified and this does work in RegExPal**) but I thought I would throw this out there as another way to do what you need, that may be a little easier to understand:

```
^(?!Account|Public|[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\.)[a-zA-Z_0-9/.]+$
```

Explained:

```
^                   # start
(?!                 # open a negative lookahead
Account|Public|     # ignore both Account and Public
[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\.     # ignore files in root (i.e., letters/numbers, followed by period)
)                   # close negative lookahead
[a-zA-Z_0-9/.]+     # now match anything with letters/numbers, periods and slashes, but no '?' (ignores URLs with query string)
$                   # end
```

Comment: I think that this requires files in root to end with a period, which is incorrect. The period will virtually never be at the end of the string; often three characters in, but sometimes more and sometimes less.

Comment: @JeffreyBlake: No, that's not how lookaheads work. Since it's a negative lookahead, as soon as it encounters a period, it matches and fails, which is what you want. The period doesn't have to be at the end. Try it and see.

Comment: JeffreyBlake: After reading the answer from @sln, I can see what's happening on RegExPal. Your regex is actually matching the last three lines of the sample input as ONE match (i.e., all three lines constitute a single match), and RegExPal doesn't display (color) the match unless you check 'Multiline anchors'. sln's answer explains why. Either my answer or sln's will do what you need, but your regex may fail at some point because it definitely is over-running line endings. sln's answer may be better since it's more general than mine, but I would hesitate to use yours in a production setting.

Comment: +1 in that this solved the question. I was debating which answer to accept here though. The redirect system this is driving actually needs the root folder and the remaining file structure to be separate matches from which it can construct the resultant replacement url. That leads me to think that what I had originally may be best (with the extra parens in the lookahead removed).

Answer (score 1):

RegexPal is confused, but the real problem is that the regex isin't designed correctly.

Not sure what you are trying to do but when using multi-line mode and the anchors `^$`
within a regex, unless you specifically design it that way, care must be taken NOT to
overflow the anchors. This applies to both greedy/non-greedy quantifiers.
Its made even worse when throwing negative lookahead conditions into the mix.

In this case, it caused RegexPal to go bonkers and apparently backtrack before `^`
without reevaluating ^ again. This is probably not a JavaScript problem though.

Adding not newline to your consumption classes fixes all the problems. It must be
added to both classes.

```
^(?!Account|Public)[^./\n]+(?:/[^?\n]*)?$
```

Comment: +1 for explaining why the problem occurred. In practice, the newline issue is not an issue, as the redirect system is processing a single URL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to use `^(?!Account|Public)([^\.\/]+\/[^\?]*)$` regex.

Take a look here: http://ideone.com/q3lAv

Then correct RegExPal pattern would be `^(?!Account|Public)([^\.\/]+\/[^\?\n]*)$`

---

**[UPDATE]**

Filename doesn't have to include dot `.` in its name and on the other hand folder/directory name may have dot `.` in its name, but if you want to have a positive match also on 7th line, then you should go with the pattern `^(?!Account|Public)([^\.\/]+(?:\/[^\?]*|[^\.\?]*))$` and it should work also as the RegExPal pattern.

Take a look here: http://ideone.com/VcmEP

Comment: That fails to match on the 7th item. Also, I'm pretty sure you do not need to escape `/` ever, and you do not need to escape `.` inside `[]`

Comment: @JeffreyBlake - It is safer to escape `/` and `.` and it is pretty standard for regex, as some languages require that (e.g. *Perl*). Besides of that, why you want 7th item to match? File doesn't need to have dot in name. But... if that's what you are looking for, then see my updated answer above. Thank you for considering my answer.